# Recess Relationship Annotation issue

Tags: database, orm, annotations, recess

I'm running into a severe problem, In fact I'm not well understanding recess naming convention for relationship. I personally think it should be more documented with concrete examples. Hopefully, if i get to understand it, I can start to write some examples.Also, if someone has well understand Recess relationship convention well, in case, he can explain it here, it would be great

I have two table, all table names are in the database are the lower case of the model names. All fields names are same to the models' attributes
Post---->Comment(A Post can have several comments)

**Model Post:**

```
<?php
/**
 * !Database Default
 * !Table post
 * !HasMany comment, Class:try.models.Comment,Key:postId
 */
class Post extends Model 
{
        /** !Column PrimaryKey, Integer, AutoIncrement */
        public $postId;

        /** !Column String */
        public $name;

}
?>
```

**Model Comment:**

```
<?php
/**
 * !Database Default
 * !Table comment
 * !BelongsTo post
 */
class Comment extends Model {
        /** !Column PrimaryKey, Integer, AutoIncrement */
        public $commentId;

        /** !Column String */
        public $name;

}
?>
```

However, when I'm doing the following, I'm getting an error

```
<?php
Library::import('try.models.Post');
Library::import('try.models.Comment');

Library::import('recess.framework.controllers.Controller');

/**

 * !RespondsWith Layouts

 * !Prefix Views: home/, Routes: /

 */

class TryHomeController extends Controller {



        /** !Route GET */

        function index() 
        {               

                $this->flash = 'Welcome to your new Recess application!';

                $Post= new Post(5);
                $Comments=$Post->comment();
        }



}

?>
```

However, I'm getting this error

**try.models.Comment has not been imported.**

Comment: What are the names of you controller an model class files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your Post model at the Class line

```
**
* !Database Default
* !Table post
* !HasMany comment, **Class:try.models.Comment**,Key:postId
*/
```

Here you are including the full classpath, *try.models.Comment*. You only need to specify *Comment* as the class to include. Be sure that your file names follow the ClassName.class.php convention.